# How to use media-queries to change the html

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I'm just reading about media queries for the first time, so that I can make my web page look different on a smartphone.

I see how I can use them to apply different styles to the web page, e.g.

```
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 320px) 
  and (max-device-width: 480px)
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {

    body {
            color: green; 
         }

}
```

But how do I use them to change the HTML? For example, if I want to add a line break between two images only if the page is being viewed on a smartphone.

So on a laptop, the images would appear side-by-side and on the smartphone, one would be above the other.

Many thanks.

Comment: I guess you are looking for something like a responsive layout. Try searching how to design a responsive HTML page in google. We get many search results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different ways to achieve what you wanted.

Like you will design your website using mobile-first or desktop-first approach etc.

You can try to read this link about RWD

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

and to know more about RWD read this link

http://blog.froont.com/9-basic-principles-of-responsive-web-design/

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add margin bottom for that image with border_bottom and that should imitate the line break. Set:

```
 @media only screen 
  and (max-device-width: 480px) {
    img {
            border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
            margin-bottom: 15px; 
         }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd look into the viewport too...

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp

It lets you scale down a website so (usually) text is more readable on small devices like mobile phones.